# Last Wiki version for EE 2

Tags: ee2, wiki

Wiki version 2.3.

Anyone know what the last available version of the first-party Wiki module is for EE2? I have some old wiki living somewhere on a site, and it's pulling this crap:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9

SELECT r.*, m.member_id, m.screen_name, m.email, m.url, p.page_namespace, p.page_name AS topic FROM exp_wiki_revisions r, exp_members m, exp_wiki_page p WHERE p.last_updated = r.revision_date AND m.member_id = r.revision_author AND r.page_id = p.page_id AND r.revision_status = 'open' AND r.wiki_id = '1' ORDER BY p.last_updated DESC LIMIT

Filename: modules/wiki/mod.wiki.php

Line Number: 1518
```

at this address `/Special:Recentchanges_Atom`. I honestly don't have time to debug something that's pretty damn underused, but it shows up as broken links with our web governance tool, and I just wish to be rid of it. I'm hoping we just missed a sub-version upgrade or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same error with Wiki 2.3 and EE 2.10.1. That SQL query should specify a number for the limit e.g. LIMIT 10.

The easiest way to fix it is to change the template code for wiki_special_atom.html. Change the line (I'm using the default theme):

> {wiki:recent_changes}

to

> {wiki:recent_changes limit="10"}

The best way is to fix mod.wiki.php but I don't have time for that either. :)

Comment: Heeeey nice catch. Yea, exactly, I didn't even know there was a Wiki on my site until someone complained, lawl. Thanks!